# Uploading the image to a particular URL which is on other server and save the image in the DB at same time

Tags: c#, image

I want to upload the image to a particular URL and save the image in the DB at same time in C#.

For example i want to upload the image to localhost:5436/nik/potrait and want to save the file path on which it is going to save in DB also from c#.

I use this code to save the image

```
image.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(PortraitFileName),
           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But it requires virtual path not physical path. Can anybode help.

Comment: just remove the `MapPath` if you want to use absolute paths

Comment: Not working. i tried but it is giving error that underlying provider failed to open.

Comment: I guess your IIS (or whatever) AppPool does not run under a user having write-access to the folder